# iOS 6 NSDictionary from JSON File

Tags: ios, xcode, json, ios6, nsdictionary

I am building a project using story boards and a `MasterView` layout. I'm trying to get the `UITableView` data from a JSON file (http://afterimagedesign.tk/topHits.json I don't know if this is correct JSON or not, I'm new) so I call these methods in `viewDidLoad()`

```
responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
NSURLRequest *topHitsRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURLURLWithString:@"http://afterimagedesign.tk/topHits.json"]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:topHitsRequest delegate:self];
```

and then in `connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` method, I call this:

```
[connection release]
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[responseData release];
NSDictionary *topHitsDictionary = [responseString JSONValue];
NSArray *topHitsArray = [topHitsDictionary valueForKey:@"title"];
```

The problem is (I think) that I get this error: "Instance method '-JSONValue' not found." I have looked for this for a while, and all of the tutorials I've seen use this method. Is it iOS 6 or something else? Thanks!

EDIT:

How do I add it to a UITableView? I tried `cell.textLabel.text = [self.topKpop objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` but I keep getting a SIGABRT error. I have gotten SIGABRT error, but this time it's in the .m file.

Comment: It looks like you are using Max Kramer's extension for JSON parsing. Most likely , you forgot to import `JSON.h`

Comment: Oh yeah. Thank you! But I like the NSJSONSerialization better because I don't have to import anything.

Comment: There's no problem in importing code. It's basically using `NSJSONSerialization` , just making it easier for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the tutorials were using [`SBJson`](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) or similar JSON parser frameworks.

If you don't want to use any external frameworks, you can try [`JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData%3aoptions%3aerror%3a) from the `NSJSONSerialization` class, which is available since iOS 5.0.

```
[connection release]
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSDictionary *topHitsDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonError];
NSArray *topHitsArray = [topHitsDictionary valueForKey:@"title"];
// ...
[responseData release];
```

Comment: Thanks! It ended up that I was using Max Kramer's extension but I like the built in way better.

Comment: Now it's saying BAD_ACCESS_CODE when I put `self.topKpop = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[topHitsDictionary valueForKey:@"author"], nil];`. Oh boy.

Comment: Could you do this instead? `self.topKpop = [topHitsDictionary objectForKey:@"author"];` Also, you may want to pass `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` as the `options` in `JSONObjectWithData`.

Comment: I'll have to try that tomorrow because my dev computer is at a different location. Thanks though!

Comment: I had to move the `[responseData release]` to the end of the method. That's why!

Comment: Oh right! I took out that line without putting it back in at the end. I've updated my answer.